# Adding userform inputs to email VBA Code to body of email

Tags: excel, email, macros, vba

I need to be able to send an email from Excel, but I want the body of the email to contain values from a userform after you press submit.

I have tried different things, but I am stuck with the below code.

```
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'set Importance
aEmail.Importance = 2
'Set Subject
aEmail.Subject = "TestMailSend"
'Set Body for mail
aEmail.Body = "Campaign Name" & Me.ComboBox5.Value
              "Job Number" & Me.ComboBox4.Value
              "Revenue" & Me.ComboBox3.Value


'send one off to 1 person use this static code
'aEmail.Recipients.Add "E-mail.address-here@ntlworld.com"
aEmail.Recipients.Add "Insert email address here"
'Send Mail
aEmail.Send
```

Comment: What is really your problem? Do you have code in your userform? Btw, you should use `&` to concatenate data of you email body

Comment: This is the problem:   aEmail.Body = " Campaign Name" Me.ComboBox5.Value
              " Job Number" Me.ComboBox4.Value
              " Revenue" Me.ComboBox3.Value

Comment: Did you check my answer already to see if it solves the problem?

Comment: Did it work as you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change the following:

```
'Set Body for mail
aEmail.Body = "Campaign Name: " & Me.ComboBox5.Value & chr(10) & _
              "Job Number: " & Me.ComboBox4.Value & chr(10) & _
              "Revenue: " & Me.ComboBox3.Value
```

The `&` merges two values, the `chr(10)` adds a newline and the `_` lets you write multiline code.

HTH ;)

Comment: Thank you, that has solved the problem. It all goes on one sentence though. is there a way to adjust to make it multi line so that each record shows on it's own line? Really appreciate your support.

Comment: That's brilliant. Works great. Thanks for your help and I hope this contributes to the site. Scott

Comment: If you are satisfied with the solution maybe you could accept the answer? :)